# git with maven-release-plugin and buildnumber-maven-plugin

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin, buildnumber-maven-plugin

When perform release I try to store the value of ${scmBranch} from buildnumber-maven-plugin to MANIFEST.MF file in my jar. But value is "UNKNOWN" and

```
.../target/checkout/git branch
```

say:

```
* (no branch)
```

revision same as tag revision.

What to do with it?

Comment: Try with `${SCMBranch}` (note the case).

Comment: The value of ${SCMBranch} is "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change release goals to

```
-Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform -Darguments='-DscmBranch=${BRANCH}'
```

solve problem.